# Combine Rows in BigQuery Standard SQL Ignoring Nulls and filter to fullest row in efficient way

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069852/combine-rows-in-bigquery-ignoring-nulls/50070542?noredirect=1#comment93876458_50070542) which gets me almost there, but I'd like to only return the rows that have the fullest amount of data.

Extending the solution example from the question linked above:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'first_data' col_1, NULL col_2,  '4/22' updated UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,     NULL,             'old',        '4/23'         UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,     NULL,             'correct',    '4/24'         UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,    'next_data',       NULL,         '4/25'         UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,     NULL,             NULL,         '4/26'  
  SELECT 2,     NULL,             'old',        '4/23'         UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,     'this_one',        NULL,        NULL,          UNION ALL            
)
SELECT id, 
  IFNULL(col_1, FIRST_VALUE(col_1 IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win)) col_1, 
  IFNULL(col_2, FIRST_VALUE(col_2 IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win)) col_2, 
  updated
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updated DESC 
               ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER BY id, updated
```

I would like the result to look like:

```
id  col_1       col_2   updated     
1   next_data   correct 4/26 
2   this_one    old     4/23
```

I tried this by using `ROW_NUMBER()` and it works, but it was suggested it is not very memory efficient:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(n) FROM (
    WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
      SELECT 1 id, 'first_data' col_1, NULL col_2,  '4/22' updated UNION ALL
      SELECT 1,     NULL,             'old',        '4/23'         UNION ALL
      SELECT 1,     NULL,             'correct',    '4/24'         UNION ALL
      SELECT 1,    'next_data',       NULL,         '4/25'         UNION ALL
      SELECT 1,     NULL,             NULL,         '4/26'         UNION ALL
      SELECT 2,     NULL,             'old',        '4/23'         UNION ALL
      SELECT 2,     'this_one',        NULL,        NULL                     
    )
    SELECT id, 
      IFNULL(col_1, FIRST_VALUE(col_1 IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win)) col_1, 
      IFNULL(col_2, FIRST_VALUE(col_2 IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win)) col_2, 
      updated,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) as n
    FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
    WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY updated DESC 
                   ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
    ORDER BY id, updated)
 WHERE n = 1
```

which gives:

```
id  col_1       col_2   updated     
1   next_data   correct 4/26 
2   this_one    old     4/23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'first_data' col_1, NULL col_2,  '4/22' updated UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,     NULL,             'old',        '4/23'         UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,     NULL,             'correct',    '4/24'         UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,    'next_data',       NULL,         '4/25'         UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,     NULL,             NULL,         '4/26'         UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,     NULL,             'old',        '4/23'         UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,     'this_one',        NULL,        NULL                 
)
SELECT id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(col_1 IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] col_1,
  ARRAY_AGG(col_2 IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] col_2,
  MAX(updated) updated
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
GROUP BY id
```

with result

```
Row id  col_1       col_2       updated  
1   1   next_data   correct     4/26     
2   2   this_one    old         4/23
```

Comment: Neat thanks, I'll look at this tomorrow with the real example!

Comment: Great thanks - my data actually didn't have the updated column so I just took `ARRAY_AGG(col1 IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] col1,` etc but this answer will be useful for other cases as well, thanks again.